# How do I troubleshoot email not sending in Redmine?

Tags: email, redmine

I'm trying to figure out why my Redmine install isn't sending out email (e.g. notification on issue update, etc). My configuration.yml file is configured as so:

```
production:
  email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :sendmail
```

I've also tried configuring for SMTP with the same non-results:

```
 production:
   email_delivery:
     delivery_method: :smtp
     smtp_settings:
       enable_starttls_auto: true
       address: "smtp.gmail.com"
       port: 587
       domain: "smtp.gmail.com"
       authentication: :plain
       user_name: "xxxxxxxx@gmail.com"
       password: "xxx"
```

I don't know how to troubleshoot this. Is there a log that errors are written to? I've already checked the production.log but it didn't have any helpful hints. Thanks for your help.

```
RAILS_ENV=production script/about
/home/ootbdv/.gems/gems/coderay-1.0.9/lib/coderay/helpers/file_type.rb:19: warning: already initialized constant UnknownFileType
/home/ootbdv/.gems/gems/coderay-1.0.9/lib/coderay/helpers/file_type.rb:126: warning: already initialized constant TypeFromExt
/home/ootbdv/.gems/gems/coderay-1.0.9/lib/coderay/helpers/file_type.rb:132: warning: already initialized constant TypeFromShebang
/home/ootbdv/.gems/gems/coderay-1.0.9/lib/coderay/helpers/file_type.rb:138: warning: already initialized constant TypeFromName

Environment:
  Redmine version                          2.3.0.stable.11680
  Ruby version                             1.8.7 (x86_64-linux)
  Rails version                            3.2.13
  Environment                              production
  Database adapter                         MySQL
Redmine plugins:
  no plugin installed
```

(I don't know why I'm getting those warnings. If anyone knows how to get rid of them, please let me know.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know the answer to the question, but I fixed my problem (not getting Redmine to send emails) by toggling back to `sendmail`. If you're running into this problem, you might just want to try going back to `sendmail`.

Comment: I know this is an old thread but, could you @Avery explain more how did you solve it? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly are you asking one or two questions? would like you multiple answers?

I think it's recommended not have the password in quotes. Your smtp config looked good apart from that.
You should see entries in /var/log/email.log

Have no clue on the last part of your question, is it even related? I doubt it.